# Showing that addition is well defined on the rational numbers.

Tags: real-analysis

I am self-studying real analysis and have just worked through the construction of the rational numbers. The rational numbers, $\mathbb{Q}$, were defined as follows:
$$\mathbb{Q} = \left\{\dfrac{m}{n}: m, n \in \mathbb{Z}, n \neq 0 \right\}$$ where $\dfrac{m}{n}$ is the class of ordered pairs $(m, n)$ such that $(m, n) \sim (p, q)$ if $mq = pn$ with $n, q \neq 0$.

My first question is regarding the last statement, $mq = pn \Rightarrow (m,n) \sim (p, q)$. Shouldn't this statement be written, "...is the class of ordered pairs $(m, n)$ such that if $(m, n) \sim (p, q)$, then $mq = pn$ with $n, q \neq 0$? The proof below seems to depend on the implication going this way, unless this statement is actually an IFF statement?

My second question is regarding proving that addition is well-defined. The professor suggestion the following starting point:

$$\dfrac{a}{b} \sim \dfrac{a'}{b'} \text{ and } \dfrac{c}{d} \sim \dfrac{c'}{d'} \Rightarrow \dfrac{ad + bc}{db} \sim \dfrac{a'd' + b'c'}{b'd'}.$$

$\underline{\text{Proof}}$:

$$\text{Let } \dfrac{a}{b} \sim \dfrac{a'}{b'} \text{ and } \dfrac{c}{d} \sim \dfrac{c'}{d'} \text{ be written as } ab' = a'b \text{ and } cd' = c'd \text{, respectively,} $$
$$ \text{and } a = \dfrac{a'b}{b'} \text{ and } c = \dfrac{c'd}{d'} \textbf{   (**)}$$
$$ \text{So } \dfrac{ad + bc}{bd} = \dfrac{\dfrac{a'b}{b'}d + b\dfrac{c'd}{d'}}{db} = \dfrac{(bd)\dfrac{a'}{b'} + (bd)\dfrac{c'}{d'}}{bd} = \dfrac{a'}{b'} + \dfrac{c'}{d'} = \dfrac{a'd' + b'c'}{d'b'}$$.
$$\blacksquare$$

My first concern is that I am overcomplicating this proof. My second concern lies at the double asterisk line $\textbf{(**)}$ - can I legitimately use division like this? I know that division is defined on the naturals, but I'm having difficulties in seeing that this sort of division is equivalent.

I'm a neuroscience major, and this is purely for my own self-development so please forgive any grave errors I may have committed. Any direction, suggestions, constructive criticism, etc. from you lovely, brilliant mathematics people would be greatly appreciated! Help me bring some mathematical rigor to biology (it's desperately needed there). :)

Comment: I think we are *defining* the equivalence relation $\sim$ to be such that $(a,b) \sim (c,d)$ if $ad = bc$.  Now, even though in definitions we write "if", we really mean "iff".  That is, when you see $(a,b) \sim (c,d)$, we know by definition it means $ad = bc$.  Similarly, if $ad = bc$, then by definition of $\sim$, $(a,b) \sim (c,d)$.  So we use "if" in math definitions when we really mean "iff".  You can find extensive discussions about this on stackexchange, just google search something like "math definitions if vs iff".

Comment: Definitely useful. Thanks!

Comment: The sense of "if" here in defining the equivalence relation $\sim$ is "whenever" rather than logical implication. The definition tells us that the relation $\sim$ is equivalent to the condition $mq=pn; n, q \neq 0$. If this weren't so, the statement would not be a complete definition as it purports to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can not use the $(**)$. Even though $\frac{a'b}{b'}$ and $\frac{c'd}{d'}$ are both integers when you pull out $bd$ out of the expression $\frac{\frac{a'b}{b'}d+b\frac{c'd}{d'}}{bd}$ you are using the addition of rational number which you want to prove well defined.

Instead use the definition of the equivalence relation to prove that $(ad+bc)d'b'=(a'd'+b'c')bd$ which will prove the equality.

Comment: Got it! Thank you, my friend.

Comment: http://www.math.ucsb.edu/~helena/teaching/math8/handouts/rational.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Let $\frac{a}{b}$ ~ $\frac{a'}{b'}$ denote the equivalence class with members satisfying $ab'=a'b$.

Let us define addition as follows:

$$ \frac{a}{b} +\frac{c}{d} =\frac{ad+bc}{bd}, $$ which implies that $(ad+bc,db)$ ~$ (a'd'+b'c', b'd')$.

Now by using the topmost equivalence relation condition, we can say that:  $$(ad+bc)b'd'=(a'd'+b'c')bd.$$ Let us now  expand the brackets and use substitution of the equivalence definition ($ab'=a'b$) on the left hand-side:
$$adb'd'+bcb'd'= (ab')dd'+(cd')bb'=(a'b)dd'+(c'd)bb'=(a'd'+b'c')bd .$$
This is exactly the expression we wished to prove.